# why doesn't this c programme  print the first printf statement?

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
      while(1)
      {

              fprintf(stdout,"hello-out");
              fprintf(stderr,"hello-err");
              sleep(1);
      }
      return 0;
}
```

On compiling this programme in gcc and on executing it only prints hello-err and not hello-out.Why is that so?Can someone please explain the reason behind it?

Comment: Where did you look your printed text? First `printf` is printing to `stdout` and second to `stderr`. In your case that might be to different output streams

Comment: @JimBuck-I am working on Fedora linux.

Comment: @Nekto-I think both stdout and stderr outputs are directed to the terminal.Because I am able to see hello-err in the terminal.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you add a `'\n'` to your message it will (or should), ie. `"hello-out\n"`.

The reason being is that `stdout` is *buffered* in order to be more efficient, whereas `stderr` doesn't buffer it's output and is more appropriate for error messages and things that need to be printed immediately.

`stdout` will *usually* be *flushed* when:

- A newline (`\n`) is to be printed
- You read in from `stdin`
- `fflush()` is called on it

**EDIT:** The other thing I wanted to add before my computer crashed...twice...was that you can also use `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` to disable buffering of `stdout`. I've done that before when I've had to use `write()` (Unix) and didn't want my output to be buffered.

Comment: @bornfree: no worries, hope I explained it ok.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't *always* print out the output to stdout because by design stdout is BUFFERED output, and stderr is unbuffered.  In general, the for a buffered output stream, the stream is not dumped until the system is "free" to do so. So data can continue buffering for a long while, before it gets flushed. If you want to force the buffer to flush you can do so by hand using `fflush`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
      while(1)
      {

              fprintf(stdout,"hello-out");
              fflush(stdout); /* force flush */
              fprintf(stderr,"hello-err");
              sleep(1);
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Update: *stdout* is linebuffered when connected to a terminal, and simply buffered otherwise (e.g. a redirect or a pipe)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot newlines (noted `\n`) in your strings. Or you need to call `fflush(NULL);` or at least `fflush(stdout);` before `sleep(1);`

And `fprintf(stdout, ...)`  is the same as `printf(...)`

You need to output newlines or to call `fflush` because (at least on Linux) the `stdout` FILE buffer is line-buffered. This means that the C library is buffering data, and will really output it (using the [`write`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) Linux [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)) when the buffer is full enough, or when you flush it either with a new line, or by calling `fflush`. Buffering is needed because system calls are costly (calling `write` for every byte to be output is really too slow). Read also the man page of [setbuf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setbuf)

Comment: Can you please elaborate why is that required?I want to understand the reason behind it.

Comment: AusCBloke's answer explains it.

Comment: as others have answered, because it's buffered to reduce I/O operations. calling fflush() would force the buffer to be flushed.