# C programming about scanf (The case where the program reads multiple variables)

Tags: c

I need some help in figuring this out. I want to prompt the user to enter a list of numbers. The program is then supposed to read the given number(s).

So for example :

```
printf("Enter the cells that you would like occupied:");
```

I tried `scanf("%d", &i);` but the program doesn't know how to read it.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't know how to read it"?

Comment: whats your actual question ? you need to enter more than one variable ?

Comment: This is the program that I'm aiming for: The user enters the number of cells and then the user is prompted with the question over which of the cells s/he would like occupied. For example a user enters 10 cells and then indicates that cells 3 and 4 are occupied would have this result:

Comment: 0123456789 with a ? underneath 3 and 4

Comment: For further details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077759/c-programming-occupying-cells. Sorry if this question was in any way confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot a terminating `\n` newline character in your `printf` format string, or you need to call `fflush`. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061019/why-doesnt-this-c-programme-print-the-first-printf-statement).

What do you mean by "the program doesn't know ho to read it" ?

Did you compile your program with *all warnings enabled*, and for debugging (i.e. `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux)?

Did you debug your program using a debugger (like `gdb` on Linux)?