# My c code can't run by order

Tags: c

I'm writting a small code, just five lines, but it can't runs as the correct order.
After compiling this code, It will exec `"dir"` first and then print my string.

But if I change it to `printf ("%s\n", "asdf");`, the program will run with correct order.
And I want to know why it will be this.  (PS, my computer is arch with gcc 4.6.2 and I also use clang but they have the same result.)
                                      Thank you every one.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    printf ("%s", "asdf");
    system ("dir");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it *looks* like `dir` is being executed before the `printf` is because `printf` prints to `stdout` and `stdout` buffers its output - your program *is* being executed in the correct order. `stdout`'s buffer is *usually* flushed when (as I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061019/why-doesnt-this-c-programme-print-the-first-printf-statement/8061104)):

- A newline (`'\n'`) is to be printed
- You read in from `stdin`
- `fflush()` is called on it

That is why adding a newline (`'\n'`) the string being printed causes `"asdf"` to be printed before the output of `dir`.

Other alternatives to flushing the buffer include printing to `stderr`, which isn't buffered, or using `setbuf(stdout, NULL);` to disable buffering altogether for `stdout`. Neither of these two approaches seem necessary for your situation, however.

Answer (score 5):

I assure you that your code is running in order. Probably, `printf` prints to a buffer which is not cleared by your program so the output from `dir` goes straight to the terminal while the output from `printf` waits until the output buffer is cleared which occurs when your program exits. The buffer is also cleared when you print a newline `\n` which is why printing `"%s\n"` appears to work but just `"%s"` appears to fail.

Answer (score 3):

`\n` signals that the buffer can be printed on some systems (like Solaris). That's a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
printf("%s\n", "asdf");
fflush (NULL); // or at least fflush(stdout)
system ("dir");
```

but that is still very ugly and non portable code. To traverse a directory, did you consider [readdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) & friends?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, `readdir` isn't really portable either (unless using some additional third party header/lib).

Comment: I think it is POSIX, so is standardized... I agree that not all systems even have the notion of directories... Standard C only knows about files...

Answer (score 1):

For sure, the order is always correct. I suppose you think execution order is incorrect as the console shows the text lines generated by "dir" before the printf output. But that doesn't mean that one is done before the other. I don't know how the printing buffer works in your system, but for sure there are a buffer of text that each process send to any output pipe.

My guess is that text buffers to output streams are flushed immediately when a CR char appears. So, if you don't write the '\n' char, the process that runs "dir" (a os system process your are invoking) flushes its output before your process does.